# unarchiveFromFile returning 'nil' in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an Xcode game I would like to run, but get an error when doing so:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Code looks like this:

```
class func unarchiveFromFile(file: String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "sks") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            let sceneData = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let archiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: sceneData)
            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKNode
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The line "let archiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: sceneData) - is where the error occurs. I have tried to change it to 'forReadingWith', which worked, but it still gives me an yellow error saying it was removed in iOS 12 or something. So is that a long term solution to just use 'forReadingWith'? Or is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: Why are you doing this weird elaborate dance? The way to read an _sks_ file is just to say `let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: file)`.

Comment: This was the old way prior to iOS 9,  SKNodes can be loaded via their initializer now, as @matt has pointed to an example of how to load an SKScene.